# Losing results from a triple for loop

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

I' m trying to do some matches between an np.array and some folders/images I have.
I' m positive that i have created a 1 to 1 match for all my data.
So I' m guessing I lose results from the way my for loops are structured, don't know why though.

My np.array has the following structure (ArtistName, Song, Sentiment):

1. ['Singer1' 'song1' 'Sad']
2. ['Singer1' 'song2' 'Excited']
3. ['Singer2' 'song1' 'Sad']
4. ['Singer2' 'song2' 'Afraid']
5. ...
6. ['Singer5229' 'song25' 'Afraid']

etc, aggregated to 5229 registries

My folders' names have the artists' names and inside those folders are images (spectograms) named after the songs.
My aim is to match 1 to 1 the registries so I can create my X,y tables, where X will be an image vector and y the sentiment, so to train a CNN later.
I lose about 1k of matchings though.
My code is as follows:

```
spectoPath = '/home/mike/Spectograms'

X = []
y = []

i = 0

for folder in os.listdir(spectoPath):
  for image in os.listdir(spectoPath + '/' + folder):
    for x in range(len(artistTrackSentiment)):
      if '/' in artistTrackSentiment[x][1]:
        artistTrackSentiment[x][1] = artistTrackSentiment[x][1].replace("/", "_")
      if folder == artistTrackSentiment[x][0] and image == artistTrackSentiment[x][1]+'.png':
        i += 1
        img = cv2.imread(spectoPath + '/' + folder + '/' + image)
        resized_image = cv2.resize(img, (256, 256))

        # plt.imshow(resized_image)

        X.append(np.asarray(resized_image))
        y.append(artistTrackSentiment[x][2])
        # print(X)
        # print(y)

print("Matches found", i)
```

Comment: Question has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `deep-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0):

i think you lose your data cause you assign a new value

```
if '/' in artistTrackSentiment[x][1]:
    artistTrackSentiment[x][1] = artistTrackSentiment[x][1].replace("/", "_")
```

and after them you compare....

```
if folder == artistTrackSentiment[x][0] and image == artistTrackSentiment[x][1]+'.png':
    i += 1
    ...
```

so every image which include a `/` is lost...

Comment: Actually with or without this block of code i get the same results. I was hoping to get at least +50 more results with this replacement. It was actually been added because in the np.array there are some songs with '/' in their name, whilst I can't have a folder with '/' in its name in my folder path. So I replaced it with '_'

Comment: can you post real data and the matching entry in your array of an lost datapoint... just add a `else: print(artistTrackSentiment[x])`  and post the output